# Simple Expand/collapse divs

Tags: jquery

how can i make it to work, when clicked expand it and when clicked again collapse it...
if it is already expand then say hide and if it is already collapse then say show.

below is the code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Collapsible Message Panels</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        *
        {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        #content
        {
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px dotted #999999;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: justify;
        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Hide the "view" div.
            $('one').hide();
            $('second').hide();
            // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
            $('div.slide').click(function () {
                // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
                $('second').hide();
                $('one').slideToggle(400);
                return false;
            });
            $('div.slide1').click(function () {
                // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
                $('one').hide();
                $('second').slideToggle(400);
                return false;
            });


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="slide">
        <a href="#" class="slide">Disclaimer-1</a></div>
    <div class="slide1" >
        &nbsp; &nbsp; | &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#" class="slide1">Behavior</a></div>
    <div id="one" class="content">
       As you can see the structure, the elements of the menu are inside the div with class “menu_list”. 

    </div>
    <div id="second" class="content1">
       I’m not a good color chooser so please forgive me for the color combinations. Above CSS code is straight  
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bro I had this answer for your previous question but by the time i replied you removed it :) - is this you want? http://jsfiddle.net/5TfJy/ Please let me know I will set it as answer, cheerios!

Comment: Tats: sorry bro yea the question was not cleared so anyway would it be possible to have just two links in my post and have the nice div and what you have is very nice i liked it but the requirement i have is simple two hyperlnks and once clicked expand the div with nice border and padding to it and change the title and when i clicked the second link do the same thing... its same concept expand and collapse. - thanks for looking.

Comment: Yeah bro cool I will set both as the answers yea :) gimme 2 mins I have pasted another verion anyways and done forget to upvote and accept, have a nice one bruv! cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hiya Here you go man **workingDemo** http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/  **second the 2 links together here** http://jsfiddle.net/gVjFs/3/ (using span instead of div)

**Final with toggling text here** http://jsfiddle.net/KpqvE/

2nd **demo** from a fancy one as mentioned in the comments above: http://jsfiddle.net/5TfJy/2/ (this demo only have 2 tabs.

Whichever suits you best bruv. And the code will make it clear what was missed i.e. `#` for ids.

Hope this helps does the beahviour you mentioned :)

**HTML using span instead of div** http://jsfiddle.net/KpqvE/

```
<span class="slide">
    <a href="#" class="slide">Disclaimer-1</a></span>
<span class="slide1" >
    &nbsp; &nbsp; | &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#" class="slide1">Behavior</a></span>
<div id="one" class="content">
   As you can see the structure, the elements of the menu are inside the div with class “menu_list”. 

</div>
<div id="second" class="content1">
   I’m not a good color chooser so please forgive me for the color combinations. Above CSS code is straight  
</div>
<br />
<br />​
```

**Jquery (old)**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        // Hide the "view" div.
        $('#one').hide();
        $('#second').hide();
        // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
        $('div.slide').click(function () {
            // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
            $('#second').hide();
            $('#one').slideToggle(400);
            return false;
        });
        $('div.slide1').click(function () {
            // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
            $('#one').hide();
            $('#second').slideToggle(400);
            return false;
        });


    });​
```

**Updated Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Hide the "view" div.
    $('#one').hide();
    $('#second').hide();
    // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
    $('span.slide').click(function() {
        // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
        $('#second').hide();
        $('#one').slideToggle(400, function() {

            if ($(this).is(":visible"))
              $('span.slide > a').text('hide Disc');
            else
              $('span.slide > a').text('Disclaimer-1');

        });
        return false;
    });
    $('span.slide1').click(function() {
        // When clicked, toggle the "view" div.
        $('#one').hide();
        $('#second').slideToggle(400, function() {

            if ($(this).is(":visible"))
              $('span.slide1 > a').text('hide Behavior');
            else
              $('span.slide1 > a').text('Behavior');

        });
        return false;
    });


});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HBv2j/), I assume this won't almost answer your question, but at least that would give you an idea how to use `toggle()`.

Answer (score 0):

jquery has a `toggle()` function that hides if visible and shows if hidden.